# how to set {} to map instead of set in Apache JEXL syntax

Tags: java, syntax, jexl

I know that {} means set and {:} means map in JEXL. And [] mean array[] and [...] means ArrayList in JEXL. But I want to change {} from set to map and [] from array to arraylist. How to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to derive JexlArithmetic and overload the arrayBuilder()/setBuilder()/mapBuilder() so the respective (derived) builders create the instances as you see fit.